# Creating a styled string for a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to color parts of the text based on labels.  I wrote a function that cycles through and does it just fine yet it requires selection which jumps the box around quite frankly it's ugly.

Is there a way to create styled text, concatenate it, and inject it into the RichTextBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RichTextBox` can be a little weird so you'll need to test this to see, but in general the approach to stopping this is:

```
richText.SuspendLayout();
// Update properties
richText.ResumeLayout(true);
```

This instructs ensures that the control won't be redrawn until you've finished changing properties.

If you really want to ensure the view doesn't jump, you'll need to also store the selection beforehand, then reset it just before you resume the layout.

Comment: I'll test that, and yea the selection is saved and restored.  Another issue is the scroll bar.  I did some research on it and it seems like way too much work for one tiny itty bitty function.  I have a prebuilt library for formatted string building I'm going to try.

I will keep this in mind in the future though thanks!